# How to deal with slow executor in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

From my spark streaming web ui I found that there are some delay in occasionally:

[image]

And through detail information There may be a slow executor:

[image]

My question is that how to deal with those slow executors

Comment: I guess that you first need to log in into that executor and figure out what it's doing. You could also use the `thread dump` feature on the Spark UI and see if it's related to your job or not.